# Google Sheets QUERY reference a single cell value as a static column

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following example spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uv0Lj5sayraH4FOPE1qZ3coLA9A2incLuX2JYD5y7SQ/edit?usp=sharing

I have a query on Sheet 2 that references sheet1 and sheet2.  I would like to have the query return 3 columns, Name, ID, and GroupName.  GroupName should reference A1 from the sheet.
I cannot find a way to do this, but it seems that it should be possible.
Something like

```
=query({Sheet1!A:B; Sheet2!A:B},"Select Col1, Col2, A1 Col3 where Col1 is not null")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=arrayformula(query({iferror(Sheet1!A2:A/0,Sheet1!A1),Sheet1!A2:B; iferror(Sheet2!A3:A/0,Sheet2!A1),Sheet2!A3:B},"where Col2 is not null label Col1 'GroupName'",1))
```

[image]

You can alter the column order like this (`select Col2, Col3, Col1`):

```
=arrayformula(query({iferror(Sheet1!A2:A/0,Sheet1!A1),Sheet1!A2:B; iferror(Sheet2!A3:A/0,Sheet2!A1),Sheet2!A3:B},"select Col2, Col3, Col1 where Col2 is not null label Col1 'GroupName'",1))
```

Comment: This worked  Thank you!  Just out of curiosity, why is the iferror required?

Comment: For as many values in `Sheet1!A2:B` we want the column beforehand to display the contents of a single cell `Sheet1!A1`, but we can't have the output of column 1 containing one row and columns 2 and 3 containing multiple rows - that would be a mismatch in the length of this array. So we use `Sheet1!A2:A/0` (divide by zero) to generate an error for every value of `Sheet1!A2:A`. The array range (length) is the same then. The `iferror` condition then displays the single value from `Sheet1!A1`.

Comment: makes perfect sense.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by swapping the semi-colon for a comma

```
=query({Sheet1!A:B, Sheet2!A:B},"Select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1 is not null")
```

Col3 should be col A from sheet2

[image]